# How to POST to Wordpress with Basic Auth using (ba)sh cURL?

Tags: wordpress, bash, curl, quotes

## 1. What I'm trying

I'm trying to `POST` to my `Wordpress` website with (`bash`) `cURL` but what seems to be not working is the *user authorization*.

So far, what I've been attempting is

```sh
curl \
    -u ${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD} \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"title": "this is a test"}' \
    --url http://mywebsite.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/
```

## 2. What I get

```
{
    "code": "rest_cannot_create",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.",
    "data": {"status": 401}
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe the `-u` flag is not the one I'm looking for? That's what I usually try when using `BasicAuth`; is it not the case here? Is the `wp-json` specification correct?

Comment: @Flimzy, not a huge fan of deleting my `On a sidenote` section... Just because it's a little bit of sidetracking doesn't mean it wouldn't add valuable content to this question. In the end, an answer that comprises that section also would have been a better wiki page in the future, in my opinion.

Comment: The message says: "Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user." Are you sure that the user that you use is correct?

Comment: @Ljm Dullaart, yes. I've even logged out and logged in to my website to make sure of it.

Comment: Your "side note" thing is [expressly off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) (it was either a "doesn't this suck?" rant/poll, which is off-topic, or a request for an off-site resource, which is also off-topic). Even if it were a valid question, it should be asked as a separate question. One question per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question, I'm using `Basic Authentication`, which actually **needs to be enabled**.

You can do it by downloading the [WP Basic Auth](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth) Plugin from Github and then uploading, installing and activating it within your Wordpress website.

Once that's done, the question's code should work fine.

Comment: Strangely, using the same procedure with the `requests` library in `Python` doesn't seem to work. I get a `Not Acceptable` message, with the `406` status code.